# Video Calling facility in Web application using WebRTC

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, audio, video, webrtc

Trying to develop or provide a video calling facility inside my web application running on Intranet (JSF and JBoss) using WebRTC.

Now, I have some few quick questions:
a. Will using webRTC require any kind of application code to be hosted on server. Will I be able to develop application without using any kind of server.
b. Will a user on Intranet and a user on internet communicate using this WebRTC. 
c. If there is no server involved anywhere in the process, then how would I inform the another user that he needs to visit this URL in order to communicate with me.

Can anyone please shed some light on these to get me started.. I am a bit confused. Have gone through various documents and links on this, but still kind of perplexed...

Comment: Would like to know why a DOWNVOTE ??...

Answer (score 3):

If you already uses JBoss, I advise you to check out Mobicents SIP Servlets (it runs on JBoss 7) and the WebRTC demo application https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/wiki/HTML5WebRTCVideoApplication

The signalling used in SIP and goes through the Server while the Media is peer to peer

Answer (score 2):

A. Yes, you need server side functionality. What server and how you do it is up to you. (you could for example use node.js and websockets)
The code below gives an example of functionality that the server should be able to handle

```
var mess = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
switch(mess.type){
    case "answer":
        allClients.forEach(function (client){
           //Locate the correct client and send the answer to it
        });
        break;
    case "offer":
        allClients.forEach(function (client){
            //Locate the correct client and send the offer to it   
        });
        break;
    case "candidate":
        allClients.forEach(function (client){
            //Locate the correct candidate and send the candidate to it
        });
        break;
}
```

B. Yes. But I'm sure there are firewall settings that could make it troublesome. Anyway, webRTC uses ICE to help in many such cases. You will see that it produces alot of "candidate" messages that contains information that helps the peer to peer connection being set up. It is actually up to your server to relay those candidate messages to the peer.

C. Well, there is a server involved...

Answer (score 2):

Every WebRTC application needs a signaling service to enable peers to exchange media and network metadata.

To cope with NATs and firewalls, the WebRTC apps can use STUN and TURN servers, though you may not need that for an intranet.

I maintain a list of [WebRTC resources](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1idl_NYQhllFEFqkGQOLv8KBK8M3EVzyvxnKkHl4SuM8/edit), which has links to tutorials and code samples.